# Matrix norm $\|\cdot \|_{2, \infty}$ inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

It seems to be a simple question but I am a bit stuck to show

$$\|AB\|_{2,\infty} \leq \|A\|  \|B\|_{2,\infty} $$

here $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm.

Comment: In general, $\| A \|_{p,q}$ is the $q$-norm of the $p$-norms of the columns of $A$.  In this base, $\| B \|_{2,\infty}$ would be maximum of the 2-norms of the columns of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each column of $AB$ is the product of $A$ and a column of $B$. So the 2-norm of each column of $AB$ is bounded by $\|A\|$ times the 2-norm of a column of $B$. So $\|AB\|_{2,\infty} \leq \|A\| \|B\|_{2,\infty}$.